# Mongoose model, Can I do this?

Tags: mongoose

```
var category = mongoose.model('category', {
     text : String,
     todo : {
              text: String,
              done: Boolean
            }
});
```

I am making a to-do list using the `MEAN` stack. The user can add/delete categories (Ex. work /home ) and in each category will be a list of to-do's they can add/delete. Is this how should I model the data?

Edit: Also! hwo would i make the API call for the todo's ? would it be ... category.todos.find(err, category.todo) { ....}

Comment: First of all `’category'` should be `'category'` and `todo =` should be `todo :` they are `syntax` errors.

Comment: oops, fixed. so now it would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't think that there is only one discrete way of creating models to achieve your requirement, If I were you I would do something like below :**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TodoSchema = newSchema({
     whattodo : String
     , dueDate :{type:Date, default:Date.now}
});

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    type:String
    , name : String
    , __some__other__fields__ : __SOME_TYPE__
    , todos : [TodoSchema] //as each category can have multiple todos
});

var Category = mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema);

module.exports = Category;
```

**Another approach could be**

Create separate `todo` model and store the `reference` to `category` model, which is something like storing `foreign key` in RDBMS.

Comment: How would I call the todos using mongoose to access all the todos?